# Using variables in terminal

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sed, command-line

I wrote this code:

```
cat /etc/passwd | cut -d : -f1 | sed -n "${FT_LINE1}, ${FT_LINE2} p"
```

Output:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `,'
```

But I have a problem with variables `$FT_LINE1, $FT_LINE2`.
When I use constants instead of a variables, this code works correctly

```
cat /etc/passwd | cut -d : -f1 | sed -n "3, 5 p"
```

I tried to use these constructions:

```
sed -n -e "${FT_LINE1}, ${FT_LINE2} p"
sed -n "{$FT_LINE1}, {$FT_LINE2} p"
sed -n "${FT_LINE1},${FT_LINE2} p"
sed -n "${FT_LINE1}, ${FT_LINE2}" p
sed -n "$FT_LINE1, $FT_LINE2" p
```

but the error remained.

Comment: What's in the variables?

Comment: You didn't set any variables.

Comment: Thank's you all. @melpomene you're right. Problem solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in [*melpomene*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52290281/using-variables-in-terminal/52296285#comment91528490_52290281) and [*PesaThe*'s comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52290281/using-variables-in-terminal/52296285#comment91528338_52290281), `sed` address ranges can't be blank, both shell variables `${FT_LINE1}`, and `${FT_LINE2}`, must be set to some appropriate value.

This simplest way to reproduce the error is:

```
sed ,
```

Which outputs:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `,'
```

Because `,` is **not** a `sed` command, it's just a delimiter that separates range addresses.

It might help to look at some other related errors.  Let's add a starting address of *1*:

```
sed 1,
```

Output:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 2: unexpected `,'
```

Which seems unhelpful, since it should be expecting an address *after* the `,`.  Now let's add a second address of *1*:

```
sed 1,1
```

Output:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 3: missing command
```

A little better, but really it's char 4 that's missing a command, or rather there's a missing command *after* char 3.

Now let's add a command, and a bit of input and it works:

```
echo foo | sed 1,1p
```

Output:

```
foo
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for your help